# How do I build the right project when checking multiple projects in Azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, multiple-repositories

I am reading this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops

According to the link above, we can have multiple projects in one pipeline. So I have something like this:

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo1
    type: git
    name: org/repo1
    ref: test_multi_repo_pipeline
    trigger:
    - test_multi_repo_pipeline
  - repository: repo2
    type: git
    name: org/repo2
    ref: test_multi_repo_pipeline
    trigger:
    - test_multi_repo_pipeline  

stages:
- stage: Build_and_Deploy
  pool:
    name: 'myAgent'

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    condition: always()

    steps:
    - checkout: repo1
      displayName: 'repo1'
    - checkout: repo2
      displayName: 'repo2'
      
    - script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build.SourcesDirectory'
      
    - script: |
        npm run build:project_win_dev
      displayName: Building the project...

    - script: |
        npm run test:coverage
      displayName: Testing the skill...
      
    - script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build.SourcesDirectory'

name: Test
```

So when I execute this yaml I get the next output on this task "Build.SourcesDirectory":

```
 Directory of E:\Builds_VNext\Agent2_Builds\3046\s

03/24/2022  11:24 AM    <DIR>          .
03/24/2022  11:24 AM    <DIR>          ..
03/24/2022  11:24 AM    <DIR>          pipelines
03/24/2022  11:24 AM    <DIR>          repo1
03/24/2022  11:24 AM    <DIR>          repo2
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  878,801,965,056 bytes free
```

So once the "Build" task gets executed it fails because it gets executed in the root rather than in the specific project which I made the commit. So I was wondering if there is a way to know that if I made the commit in the project repo1, then the build gets done under the folder repo1 and if I made the change on repo2 then the build gets done inside repo2 folder

Thanks in advance for your help.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

So, you *could* write a conditional to determine which repo you're editing. But, I'd advise against it. You'd have to query the git history and detect changes.

The path of lease resistance is to build both every time. You'd just need to update your code to `cd` to the correct folder before building:

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: repo1
    type: git
    name: org/repo1
    ref: test_multi_repo_pipeline
    trigger:
    - test_multi_repo_pipeline
  - repository: repo2
    type: git
    name: org/repo2
    ref: test_multi_repo_pipeline
    trigger:
    - test_multi_repo_pipeline  

stages:
- stage: Build_and_Deploy
  pool:
    name: 'myAgent'

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    condition: always()

    steps:
    - checkout: repo1
      displayName: 'repo1'
    - checkout: repo2
      displayName: 'repo2'
      
    - script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build.SourcesDirectory'
      
    - script: |
        cd repo1
        ls
        echo '----'
        npm run build:project_win_dev
        echo 'Running Tests'
        npm run test:coverage
      displayName: 'Build and Test: Repo 1'

    - script: |
        cd repo2
        ls
        echo '----'
        npm run build:project_win_dev
        echo 'Running Tests'
        npm run test:coverage
      displayName: 'Build and Test: Repo 2'
      
    - script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build.SourcesDirectory'

name: Test
```

Comment: I decided going with your first suggestions, since building multiple repos one after another could affect the performance of the Azure devops pipeline

Comment: You may want to consider having entirely separate build pipelines that are triggered based on changes to specific file paths. Of course, this would only be an option if the two repos weren't dependent on eachother.

Comment: both repos are not dependent of each other both the pipeline logic is exactly the same, that's why I taught of using the multiple repos checking feature

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend the use of pipeline templates to avoid repeating logic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops